# Search / replace and move column in Large CSV file?

Tags: perl, shell, unix, scripting, sed

I have some very large files (bigger than 2GB ), and the text in the files has the following format:

```
TimeStamp,BidPrice,BidVolume,AskPrice,AskVolume
2013/4/18;22:5:42.668;13266;10;13279;10
2013/4/18;22:10:48.820;13271;10;13279;10
2013/4/18;22:12:0.956;13266;10;13279;10
...
```

I would like to accomplish the following task

- replace the 1st semi colon ";" in Timestamp to space " "
- Make the timestamp look like this format: yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss
- replace the rest semi colon ";" to comma ","
- Switch the BidVolume and AskPrice column index.

The output should look like as below

```
TimeStamp,BidPrice,AskPrice,BidVolume,AskVolume
2013.04.18 22:04:55,13256,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22:05:42,13266,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22:10:48,13271,13279,10,10
...
```

Can any one please advise me how to ? I would be very appreciated.

Comment: your example out show MM=.`4` ... you'll be much happier in the long run if you respecify as MM=.`04`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR==1 {
  print $1, $2, $4, $3, $5; next
}
{
  split($0,fld,/;/); split(fld[1],d,/\//)
  for(j=2;j<=3;j++) {
    d[j] = (length(d[j]) == 1) ? "0"d[j] : d[j]
  }
  sub(/\..*/,"",fld[2]); split(fld[2],t,/:/)
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    t[i] = (length(t[i]) == 1) ? "0"t[i] : t[i]
  }
  printf "%s.%s.%s %s:%s:%s,", d[1], d[2], d[3], t[1], t[2], t[3];
  print fld[3], fld[5], fld[4], fld[6]
}' file
```

#### Output:

```
TimeStamp,BidPrice,AskPrice,BidVolume,AskVolume
2013.04.18 22:05:42,13266,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22:10:48,13271,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22:12:00,13266,13279,10,10
```

Comment: thanks, this works but date is missing 0, how can i fix it ?
2013.04.18

Comment: @user1565287 You didn't specify that in your output.

Comment: opps.. my bad . I edited my first post, can you please make script add 0 to date also , thanks

Answer (score 2):

This short Perl program does what you ask. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and prints the modified data to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  s{^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+);(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)[^;]*}{
   sprintf '%04d.%02d.%02d %02d.%02d.%02d', $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6;
  }e;
  tr/;/,/;
  my @fields = split /,/;
  print join(',', @fields[0,1,3,2,4]), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
TimeStamp,BidPrice,AskPrice,BidVolume,AskVolume
2013.04.18 22.05.42,13266,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22.10.48,13271,13279,10,10
2013.04.18 22.12.00,13266,13279,10,10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/;/ /; s/;/,/g; s/\//./g;' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: forgetting the bid and ask.  one might ask the consumer to take awareness of that.

Comment: Thanks, are there away we can format the timestamp to yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
perl -naF"/[\/;:.]/" -pe '$_ = $. == 1 ? $_ : sprintf "%d.%02d.%02d %02d.%02d.%02d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", @F[0..5,7..10]' inFile > outFile
```

Output on your dataset:

```
TimeStamp,BidPrice,BidVolume,AskPrice,AskVolume
2013.04.18 22.05.42,13266,10,13279,10
2013.04.18 22.10.48,13271,10,13279,10
2013.04.18 22.12.00,13266,10,13279,10
```